# How do I render angular directive inside an ag-grid cellEditor Component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I'm trying to render an angular autocomplete directive in a custom ag-grid cell editor. On rendering, the directive is not compiled but rather the raw html is printed in cell editor. Is there anyway to get it to render as the angular directive?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the solution using angular's $compile to render the angular directive into html.

Code:

```
CategoryEditor.prototype.init = function (params) {
  this.container = document.createElement('div');
  this.container.tabIndex = "0";

  this.dropdown = document.createElement('div');
  this.dropdown.setAttribute("dynamic", "html");
  this.container.appendChild(this.dropdown);
  //My directive is of the form <div dynamic="html"></div>

  var that = this;
  $scope.selectedCallback = function ($item) {
    that.selectCategory($item);
    params.stopEditing();
  };
  $compile(this.container)($scope);
  $scope.$digest();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have angularCompileRows=true to get angular 1 working inside ag-Grid

Comment: Just that didn't work. I had to use $compile to get it to work.